# Что за свойство необходимо присвоить блоку?

Tags: html, css

Что за свойство необходимо присвоить html блоку, чтобы стала возможно с ним работать так же как с элементом input. То есть точно так же вводить текст, как с текстовым полем

Comment: <div contenteditable="true"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

атрибут `contenteditable="true"`, подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)